# Морфемный анализ слова

Tags: морфемы

***Столпотворение***
*Способ образования слова*: сложение в сочетании с суффиксацией.
*Основа слова*: СТОЛПОТВОРЕНИ
∩ - СТОЛП; соединительная гласная - О; ∩ - ТВОР; ∧ - ЕНИ словообразующий суффикс;  ⏰ - Е;

***Душераздирающий***
*Способ образования слова:* сложение в сочетании с суффиксацией.
*Основа слова*: ДУШЕРАЗДИРАЮЩ
∩ - ДУШ; соединительная гласная - Е; ¬ - РАЗ; ∩ - ДИР; ∧ - А словообразующий суффикс; ∧ - ЮЩ формообразующий суффикс; ⏰ - ИЙ.

***Раздражённый*** 
*Способ образования слова*: приставочно-суффиксальный
*Основа слова:* РАЗДРАЖ
¬ - РАЗ, ∩ -ДРАЖ, ∧ - ЁНН- формообразующий суффикс, ⏰ -ЫЙ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Морфологический разбор - по частям речи, а это даже не морфемный,а словообразовательный.

**Раздражённый**
Способ образования слова: суффиксальный

Раздражённый - тот, которого раздражали.